# Am i re-entering a slump, or just my bad luck?

Tags: sicilian-defense, psychology, losing

Last 2 hours was one of my most embarrassing games ever.

Yesterday I played against a chess club member and won 3-0, however the last 2 hours is so sad I lost for 3-0, all surrenders and no end-game.

Then another guy came up and challenged, he played 1. e4 c5 I know they don't have any knowledge of Sicilian nevertheless dragon, so I played with the variation of accelerated dragon and while being so unaware I lost with scholar's mate 4.Qxd7#.

Don't know what just happened to me back then, however one of my excuses was "My stomach is empty" I don't know if I'm making an excuse or not, but certainly I know there's some reason since a similar problem occurred to me when I'm learning chess.

Am i re-entering a slump, or just my bad luck?

Comment: did this all happen in one day. I would say that it may just be psychological, like a tilt.

Comment: @CognisMantis Yes, It did.

Comment: Think that it is lack of concentration. To sure to win. Happens to me once in a while :-)

Comment: In that case, your mind was probably unsettled and it was difficult to concentrate.

Comment: @4444 I must disappoint you. I am not good :-) If I was then I would not lose very often because I quickly replied and ended up with 1 piece down or being mated. Also there is nothing more difficult then winning a game in which you (think you) have an advantage.

Comment: If your stomach is indeed empty and you feel hungry, then your brain sugar level is low and unable to think

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it was luck OR a slump. I think that you were simply too exhausted from your previous games and might have been playing too fast or not being as careful with your pieces

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention time controls, psychologically speaking, that would make a big difference. I find that the faster the time control, the more likely something silly like this happens to me. I usually slow down, and play slower time controls in order to re-compose myself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. With a little bit more of reputation you will gain the ability to comment everywhere.

Comment: Sorry about that, getting used to StackExchange! I thought it was a bit like Quora but I understand now that it is not. I will be more careful in the future. Appreciate your help. Should I delete this post? I can't add it as a comment (I just tried).

PS.- I was following the example of the poster above me really.